# How to UnitTest a method that recieve and return a list of objects

Tags: java, junit4

My class is as following, it receives a string and using that create an arraylist of objects.
I am not sure how to test it.

```
 public class Company{
        private String id;
        private String name;
        ....
 }

 public List<Company> retrieve(String factories) {
        String[] fac = factories.split(",");
        List<Company> comp;
        comp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fac.length - 1; i++) {
            comp.add(new Company(fac[i], fac[i]));
        }
        return comp;
    }
```

**JUnitTest**

```
    @Test
    public void testRetrieve() {
        System.out.println("retrieve");
        String factories = "a,b,c";
        Transact instance = new Transact();
        List<Company> expResult = null; //<<<how to define this?
        List<Company> result = instance.retrieveData(factories);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
```

Comment: You need to think about what your `retrieveData` method is supposed to do. What should it return when you pass it `"a,b,c"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your expected result

```
List<Company> expResult = null;// it shouldn't be null
```

It should be what will return from your method.

Let's say when you pass

```
String factories = "some sting";
```

should return  `List x` from your method, Then create that `List x`

You can try something like this.

```
 @Test
 public void testRetrieve() {
    System.out.println("retrieve");
    String factories = "a,b,c";
    Transact instance = new Transact();
    List<Company> expResult = new ArrayList<>(); 
    Company com1=new Company("a","a");
    Company com2=new Company("b","b");
    Company com3=new Company("c","c");
    expResult.add(com1);
    expResult.add(com2);
    expResult.add(com3);
    List<Company> result = instance.retrieveData(factories);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
 }
```

I think now you can write your own test case.

Comment: As it is an array of objects I do not know how to define that.

Comment: Then you are not ready to write a unit test.  Find out and then finish the test code.

Comment: thats why I am asking the question, I did all parts except this section, I am sure I just need to initialize this array.

Comment: @Jack you need to specify the input string and the expected resulting array.

Comment: @Jason I know that I just forgot to specify the input string, my only question is how to specify the output? should I use a for loop in test case?

Comment: @Jack just create a list of the company objects you expect your method to return.

Comment: @Jason should I use a for loop in the test method to create them?

Comment: @Jack De the simplest thing allows you to define the expected output. If that is a `for` loop, then use a for-loop, if it is a simple list of statements adding objects to the list then do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should test the actual result against the expected results in unit tests.

So you "assume" that if your class is written correctly (that's what you check), then you are supposed to get a list of Company classes as you expect, that's the result.

I'll give you an easier example.
Lets suppose you are about to check with unit tests the method that makes a sum of two numbers:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

So the unit test should supply an input and verify the expected output against the actual output.

So here you go:

```
// unit test
int expectedOutput = 10;
int actualOutput = sum(3,7);

assertEquals(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
```

In other words you "make sure" that the actualOutput that the method has produced based on your inputs matches your expectation. This is how you check that the methods is implemented correctly.

Now let's get back to your example.
In fact you have to verify that the list of "Company" classes is correct.

So your expected Output is also a list, and the question is actually how you compare the actual list of companies with the expected list of companies.

In Java, given you've defined the "equals" method on the class "Company", you can safely check with assertEquals (it should work for lists, given you're using stuff like ArrayList)

The expected result can be generated like this:

```
List<Company> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(new Company(...), new Company(...));
```

Hope this helps and happy unit testing :)

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a different method for every scenario. You've tested the "empty list" scenario. Here are some others:

```
// The happy path
@Test
public void testMultipleCompanies() {
  Transact instance = new Transact();
  List<Company> companies = instance.retrieveData("firstCompany,secondCompany");
  assertTrue(companies.size() == 2);
  assertEquals(companies.get(0).getId().equals("firstCompany");
  assertEquals(companies.get(0).getName().equals("firstCompany");
  assertEquals(companies.get(1).getId().equals("secondCompany");
  assertEquals(companies.get(1).getName().equals("secondCompany");
}

// The null string scenario
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNull() {
  Transact instance = new Transact();
  instance.retrieveData(null);
}
```

Comment: The comma separated string does not contain both id and name for each company, the value is used for both fields when constructing a Company object.

Comment: You updated your question while I was writing my answer. I'll update the answer to reflect that. But Company could just take a single String then.

Comment: Sorry @Jason you weren't the asker. But the question was edited while I was writing my answer.